# How can I simplify this react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple inputs, and I am trying to make an input focus the next input once it reaches maxlength.
Here is my code:

```
handleTextChange1(e) {
    const { value, maxLength } = e.target;
    if (value.length === maxLength) {
       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.nextComponent1).focus();
    }
}
handleTextChange2(e) {
    const { value, maxLength } = e.target;
    if (value.length === maxLength) {
       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.nextComponent2).focus();
    }
}
render() {
    return (
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input onChange={this.handleTextChange1.bind(this)} maxLength="4"/>
          <input ref={c => this.nextComponent1=c} onChange={this.handleTextChange2.bind(this)} maxLength="4" />
          <input ref={c => this.nextComponent2=c}  maxLength="4"/>
       </form>
    )
}
```

I do not want each input to have a different onChange event handler.

How can I simplify this or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick simplification and to make it [DRYer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) you could pass the next component to focus as an argument to your `onChange` handler.

https://jsbin.com/cakujozoga/edit?html,js,output

```
var App = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function() {},

  handleTextChange: function(nextComponent, e) {
    const { value, maxLength } = e.target;
    if (value.length === maxLength) {
       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs[nextComponent]).focus();
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <input onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this, "nextComponent1")} maxLength="4"/>
          <input ref="nextComponent1" onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this, "nextComponent2")} maxLength="4" />
          <input ref="nextComponent2" maxLength="4"/>
       </form>
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, but I thought I should not use [ref string](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-string-attribute). Is it possible to do it with ref callback?

Answer (score 0):

Generalize your event handler:

```
focusWhenChangeHappened(component) {
  return function eventHandler(e) {
    const { value, maxLength } = e.target;
    if (value.length === maxLength) {
       ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component).focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Attaching the actual event handlers

```
... onChange={this.focusWhenChangeHappened(this.component1)} ...
... onChange={this.focusWhenChangeHappened(this.component2)} ...
```

You might have to work around `ref`s not being immediately set.